# How to get ValueMembers of CheckedListBox Checked Items?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, checkedlistbox

I have a `CheckedListBox` named Itemlist. And its `DataSource` is a data table. I have set a `DisplayMember` as "Name" , and a `ValueMember` as "NameInt". Is there a reliable way that I can loop through this `CheckedListBox` and get the `ValueMember` of the checked items?

Comment: show us code what you have tried ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a public property holding your `DataTable`:

```
public DataTable Table { get; set; }
```

Noting the `CheckedListBox` is named `Itemlist` (in case edit's occur) - and assuming `NameInt` is of `type int`, we can loop through the checked items, grab the index, then get the associated `ValueMember` directly from the source:

```
List<int> checkedValueMembers = new List();

foreach (int index in Itemlist.CheckedIndices)
{
    checkedValueMembers.Add(Table.Rows[index].Field<int>("NameInt"));
}
```

Note: I was adding the values to a list as an example, but that should give you the general idea..

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.tblResources.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   clbResources.Items.Add(new Thing()
   {
       Key = dataSet.tblResources.Rows[i]["Key"].ToString(),
       Value = dataSet.tblResources.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString()
   }, isChecked);
}
```

This is from one of my projects. Change accordingly.

Comment: this is completely out of what i asked

Comment: Please add the code you have tried, that helps understand better.